# bash -- kill command script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm looking into writing shells scripts as a prerequisite for a class and would like some help to get started. I'm currently doing a warm up exercise that requires me to write a shell script that, when executed, will kill any currently running process of a command I have given. For this exercise, I'm using the 'less' command (so to test I would input 'man ps | less').

However, since this is the first REAL script I'm writing (besides the traditional "Hello World!" one I've done), I'm a little stuck on how to start. I'm googled a lot and have returned some rather confusing results. I'm aware I need to start with a shebang, but I'm not sure why. I was thinking of using 'if' statement; something along the lines of

```
if 'less' is running
kill 'less' process
fi
```

But I'm not sure of how to go about that. Since I'm incredibly new at this, I also want to make sure I'm going about writing a script correctly. I'm using notepad as a text editor, and once I've written my script there, I'll save it to a directory that I access in a terminal and then run from there, correct?

Thank you very much for any advice or resources you could give me. I'm certain I can figure out harder exercises once I get the basics of writing a script down.

Comment: Look at the manual pages of  `ps` and `kill` and you will find what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
pgrep less && killall less
```

`pgrep less` looks process ids of any process named `less`.  If a process is found, it returns true in which case the `&&` clause is triggered.  `killall less` kills any process named `less`.

See `man pgrep` and `man killall`.

#### Simplification

This may miss the point of your exercise, but there is no real need to test for a `less` process running.  Just run:

```
killlall less
```

If no `less` process is running, then `killall` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I've tried to put this into a text editor and run it in another terminal, different from the one where the 'less' command is running, and it says 'bad interpreter: Not a directory'. When I changed the directory to where my .txt was saved, it claimed 'command not found'. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: So I've prefaced my script with 'sh' and now it seems to be doing something! In one terminal, I've run 'ps | less' and then in another, my shell script. It says "Terminated" in the first one, so I think we've done it! My only concern is when I run "ps", I see that there are 4 other 'less' processes still active... shouldn't 'killall' get rid of all of them?

Comment: @KommanderKitten Very good!  By the way, if your course is about `bash`, it would probably be better to run `bash scriptname` rather than `sh scriptname`.   On some systems, `sh` lacks all the features of `bash`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @KommanderKitten _"shouldn't 'killall' get rid of all of them?"_  Yes, it should kill all _except_ for the ones that it lacks permission to kill, such as those run by other users.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

# if one or more processes matching "less" are running
# (ps will return 0 which corresponds to true in that case):
if ps -C less
then
    # send all processes matching "less" the TERM signal:
    killall -TERM less
fi
```

For more information on available signals, see the table in the man page available via `man 7 signal`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response! A couple questions: What does '-C' do? Also, for '-TERM', a friend suggested I could use '-INT'. What is the difference, and which would be better?

Comment: Be sure to check out `man ps` for info on `-C`. Both the `INT` and `TERM` signals usually terminate a process, but both can be caught in  a signal handler, which is typically used to perform cleanup tasks before termination. `INT` will be sent to the foreground process if you press `Ctrl`+`C` in an interactive terminal session. The `KILL` signal cannot be caught and terminates a process immediately.

Comment: And as [John has pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32768011/4024473), it is not necessary to check if the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following code in bash:

```
#Tell which interpreter will process the code
#!/bin/bash

#Creating a variable to hold program name you want to serach and kill
#mind no-space between variable name value and equals sign
program='less'

#use ps to list all process and grep to search for the specific program name
# redirect the visible text output to /dev/null(linux black hole) since we don't want to see it on screen
ps aux | grep "$program" | grep -v grep > /dev/null

#If the given program is found $? will hold 0, since if successfull grep will return 0
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #program is running kill it with killall
    killall -9 "$program"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would you mind walking me through each line of code and stating what they do?

Comment: @KommanderKitten I will put some comments in the code to make it explantory.